# Ordering posts alphabetically by meta keys and title

Tags: posts, query, query-posts, post-meta

I have a query for custom posts and I have managed to order the results alphabetically based on the title first then a 2nd alphabetical ordering of the 1st of 2 meta keys "Species". This works great. But i also want to order the 2nd meta key as well.

```
<?php 
    $posts = query_posts($query_string . '&meta_key=Species&orderby=title+meta_value&order=ASC'); 
?>
```

The problem is that is would like to also order by a 2nd meta key called "Variety" so in my mind the query might look something like this but of course it doesn't work.

```
<?php 
    $posts = query_posts($query_string . '&meta_key1=Species&meta_key2=Variety&orderby=title+meta_value1+meta_value2&order=ASC'); ?>
```

Further searching has revealed something called meta_query, is this something that may help?

Comment: Yes `meta_query` will help and 1. There is not such thing as `meta_key1` and `meta_key2`. 2. Never, ever use `query_posts`, use [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instead. Specially check [multiple orderby section](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)

Comment: Thanks, yes I know no such thing was just trying to illustrate how i thought the solution "might" look.

I haven't been able to get WP_Query to work, its a taxonomy-category-name.php page with results from custom posts and I found the above query did hence its use.

Comment: I cant test because of the WP Query issue but is this going in the right direction? Sort alphabetically by title then 2 key words.

`$args = array(
 'post_type'  => 'plant-catalogue',
 'meta_query' => array(
  array(
   'key'    => 'Species',
   'key'    => 'Variety',
   'order'  => 'ASC',
  ),
 ),
 'orderby'    => 'title meta_query',
 'order'      => 'ASC',
);
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );`